# Transitioning from www.example.com/wordpress/abc to www.example.com/abc

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, cms

The existing corporate website is a non-CMS, dreamweaver dinosaur, with the top level HTML pages residing in the web root directory: `httpdocs/`.

I recently installed WordPress, and the site can now be re-implemented, page by page, in WP. Of course all the new pages have URLs that show the wordpress installation directory, e.g. `http://www.example.com/wordpress/contact-us/`

All this while, the general public will be unaware of the under-construction site in the WordPress directory, and will continue to use the existing non-CMS site.

Question is, when the WordPress site is complete, what's the recommended way to *replace* the old site? i.e. make it accessible without the `WordPress` directory in the URL.

I'm assuming that what I've done so far is common best practice, if not, please let me know too.

**UPDATE:** I just found this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

> Many people want WordPress to power their website's root (e.g. http://example.com) but they don't want all of the WordPress files cluttering up their root directory. WordPress allows you to install it into a subdirectory, but have your website served from the website root.

Answer (score 1):

Once you transfer all data and database , you can easily fire below query to change all URLS from old site to new :

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

Kindly pass your actual old and new URL in above query. This is easiest way I always use to replace URLs when transfer site from once place to another.

For you it will be :

> Old URL : www.example.com/wordpress/abc
>
> New URL : www.example.com/abc

Comment: text-replacement in the database seems like a riskier method that I had expected. I wonder what you think of this WordPress doc page I just found: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory It seems to be just what I was asking for.

Comment: For a corporate website without a blog, would you say that those 4 update queries would not be necessary?

Comment: It has not concern with blog . when you are changing site from one domain to another , above queries will help you to change all URLs.